# GUI in android NDK

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me how we can create or access GUI in Android NDK.Basically I want to reuse some existing UI components while in some places I need to create new ui components

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but I'm sure it's not practical. The speed and efficiency gains of NDK are compensating for the added complexity compared to pure Java, but I don't see the case where UI would be a bottleneck in any Android app (OpenGL heavy apps excluded).

Comment: Look into using the new NativeActivity api, I haven't used it myself so I can't really say more than that...

Comment: Why do this if you can go the opposite (and more natural) way: create a Java GUI application and move business logic (as much as you need) to native code?

Comment: i think he is just like me, both us hate using java

Answer (score 0):

Short of using Qt, which I find that option purely unacceptable at this time, you will probably need to design your own gui. I check in and see if the NDK community has grown for this, and the most recent thing I have found was Qt.

Google should give this section of android more love, before Ubuntu and others do.

Answer (score -4):

You can write new UI components in Java as subclasses of View. In fact this is how most of the system widgets are written.

Barry

Comment: This should be a comment, if anything. It wasn't what the OP was asking for.